# When converting a Byte Array to Bitmap in Java, and saving it to external storage, the image seems to be broken

Tags: java, android, image-processing

When I am trying to convert a byte array in YUV format to a bitmap and then saving that into emulated storage the image appears to be corrupted.

First I transform the yuv image to jpeg, and decode to Bitmap

```
 byte[] segments = Transform.YUVtoJPEG(yuv, obj.getInt("w"), obj.getInt("h"), 100);
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(segments, 0, segments.length);
 saveBitmapToExternalStorage(bitmap);
```

Here is Transform.YUVtoJpeg

```
 public static byte[] YUVtoJPEG(byte[] yuv, int ww, int hh, int jpegQuality) {

    // compress yuv byte array to jpeg
    final YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(yuv, ImageFormat.NV21, ww, hh,null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, ww, hh), jpegQuality, outStream);
    return outStream.toByteArray();
}
```

And here is where I save the image

```
  public static void saveBitmapToExternalStorage(Bitmap b){
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        try {
            FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outF);
            outF.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("myTag", "NOT SAVED");
        }
    }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MyTag", "Nope");
        }
}
```

Any advice is great, I'm quite stuck.
[Here are some examples of corrupted images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BpNW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VkN7.png)